# I don't receive app_account_token field in the responseBody.Latest_receipt_info

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, wwdc

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skmutablepayment/1506088-applicationusername) and WWDC sessions, applicationUsername can be get in verify an App Store receipt with UUID.
using Xcode 13.4.1, iOS 15.5

1. Use StoreKit create a consume SKPayment.
2. SKPayment.applicationUsername add a UUID string.
3. Pay success
4. Verify an App Store receipt in Sandbox. Success, but don't have
   responseBody.Latest_receipt_info and app_account_token, only in-app
   info.

```
["receipt": {

    "adam_id" = 0;

    "app_item_id" = 0;

    "application_version" = 2;

    "bundle_id" = "com.***";

    "download_id" = 0;

    "in_app" =     (

                {

            "in_app_ownership_type" = PURCHASED;

            "is_trial_period" = false;

            "original_purchase_date" = "2022-07-25 07:04:58 Etc/GMT";

            "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1658732698000;

            "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2022-07-25 00:04:58 America/Los_Angeles";

            "original_transaction_id" = 2000000113747893;

            "product_id" = "com.item_consumable1.test";

            "purchase_date" = "2022-07-25 07:04:58 Etc/GMT";

            "purchase_date_ms" = 1658732698000;

            "purchase_date_pst" = "2022-07-25 00:04:58 America/Los_Angeles";

            quantity = 1;

            "transaction_id" = 2000000113747893;

        }

    );

    "original_application_version" = "1.0";

    "original_purchase_date" = "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT";

    "original_purchase_date_ms" = 1375340400000;

    "original_purchase_date_pst" = "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles";

    "receipt_creation_date" = "2022-07-25 07:04:58 Etc/GMT";

    "receipt_creation_date_ms" = 1658732698000;

    "receipt_creation_date_pst" = "2022-07-25 00:04:58 America/Los_Angeles";

    "receipt_type" = ProductionSandbox;

    "request_date" = "2022-07-25 07:05:30 Etc/GMT";

    "request_date_ms" = 1658732730724;

    "request_date_pst" = "2022-07-25 00:05:30 America/Los_Angeles";

    "version_external_identifier" = 0;

}, "environment": Sandbox, "status": 0]
```

Comment: latest_receipt_info will Only returned for receipts containing auto-renewable subscriptions

Comment: It's mean this feature only use with  auto-renewable subscriptions pay? ?

Comment: yes  , latest_receipt_info will only be there if the subscription is auto-renewable.

Comment: Thx , the instructions about the SKPayment.applicationUsername are too vague.